# How do I compute this contour integral involving dirac delta function?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

$I = \int_0^\infty \sin{t} \space \delta(t^2 - \frac{\pi^2}{4})dt$

Substituting $t$ as $z$ I try to do the contour integral of a circle around t = 1 in the complex plane. I wonder if I can argue that the residue is at $t = \frac{\pi}{2}$. Can you give me some hints?

Comment: Must you use a contour integral? The method described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Composition_with_a_function) would likely be quicker.